# Tempo de verbo post "kiam", "dum", "post/antaŭ ol", ktp

Tags: verbs, subordinate-clauses

> You will find out when she arrives.
> You will find out after she arrives.
> You will find out while she arrives.
> You will find out when she has arrived.

Esperante, kiel rilatus la tempo de la dua verbo (alveni) al tiu de la unua (eltrovi)? Tio estas, en ĉiu frazo, ĉu la verbo estus "alvenas", "alvenos", aŭ eĉ "estos alveninta"/"alvenintos"? Mia konjekto estas aŭ "alvenos" aŭ "estos alveninta"/"alvenintos", nur pro tio, ke la dua verbo ĉiuokaze okazus post ol la unua (sed anstataŭe "alvenas" eble iufoje povus taŭgi en la tria, ĉar tiuokaze eblas ke la alveno daŭre okazus, kaj nun kaj dum la eltrovo posta). Ĉu senchavas tiu rezono?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Mi ne certas pri ĉiuj anglaj esprimoj, sed mi rezonas laŭ la sekva maniero. Ni havas du frazojn, kiuj ambaŭ okazas en estonteco:

- Vi eltrovos/ekscios.
- Ŝi alvenos.

Ni pritraktu ekzemplon post ekzemplo por analizi kiel kombini la frazojn.

**1. You will find out when she arrives.**

Vi eltrovos la tempopunkton de ŝia alveno.

- Vi eltrovos, kiam ŝi alvenos.

Alternative vi eltrovos ion je la sama tempo, kiam ŝi alvenos.

- Vi eltrovos tion, kiam ŝi alvenos.

**2. You will find out after she arrives.**

Vi eltrovos ion tuj post ŝia alveno.

- Vi eltrovos tion, kiam ŝi estos alveninta.

**3. You will find out while she arrives.**

Mi ne certas pri la angla esprimo, kion ĝi precize signifas. Ŝajnas al mi, vi eltrovos ion je la sama tempo, kiam ŝia alveno okazos.

- Vi eltrovos tion, dum ŝi estos alvenanta.

**4. You will find out when she has arrived.**

Sama kiel la ekzemplo 2, sed ne tuj post ŝia alveno.

- Vi eltrovos tion, post kiam ŝi estos alveninta.

Sume mi kredas, ke nur la frazojn 1 kaj 4 oni uzas en praktiko.